# Including a variable in a javascript regular pattern

Tags: javascript

I have a in javascript `var num = "x"`, How do i include this as part of a regular pattern:

```
var pattern = /"i want to include the variable num here"/i
```

If i was working with a string this would have been something like"

```
var str = ""+num+"";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for that.

```
var num = "x";
var strToCheck = "string x here";
var pattern = new RegExp(num, 'i');
var testResult = pattern.test(strToCheck);
```

Comment: Am having some kind of error saying invalid flag supplied to RegExp construction.

Comment: Check flags on this link . https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp Second argument to RegExp constructor is a flag which is used for defining behavior of the regular expression...